# Use of "Copy only when installing" in Embed frameworks in XCode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, build

I am using **"copy only when installing**" flag (selected) for **Embed Frameworks** under build phases. By this, my app works fine but when I stop debugger (stop from XCode) and try to launch app from simulator only, it is getting crashed on the very first screen. So, I just wanted to understand how "copy only when installing" works ?

[image]

Comment: I'm very curious to know about this as well. Does setting this flag to true help with compile times when building project?